# How to get rid of axis lines in a linechart with CSS?

Tags: css, javafx

In JavaFX, I have added a border to a LineChart with the following CSS:

```
.chart-plot-background 
{
-fx-border-color: black;
-fx-border-width: 4px;
-fx-border-insets: -2px;
}
```

And the chart looks like:

[image]

I cannot, however, figure out how to get rid of the blue "axis" lines in the middle of the border lines. What do I need to do to either make these x and y axis lines either black or invisible?

Comment: Can you post it on plunkr with more code? Its is impossible to decode with small chunk of css code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a a little difficult to know exactly what you wish to achieve.  But a general outline is below.  Hopefully it gives you further direction on how you can modify this kind of stuff yourself and you will be able to modify it to get exactly the effect you need.

*Background*

Examine the `modena.css` file which you can find inside the `jfxrt.jar` file that ships with your Oracle JDK 8 installation.  This file defines the styles for charts.  You can override these styles as needed inside a custom CSS stylesheet that you supply.

The default value for the top border color for instance is defined as:

```
.axis:top {
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent AXIS_COLOR transparent;
}
```

*Controlling Chart Style via CSS*

To turn off plotting the axis lines on the chart you can set the appropriate values of the axis border colors to `transparent` (or `null`).  For example:

```
.axis:top {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Additionally, your sample chart features grid lines, which will be drawn over the top of the custom `chart-plot-background` border that you are defining.  To prevent that occurring, you can also make the grid lines transparent.  In the sample I also commented out the `-fx-border-insets: -2px` value as that places your border underneath the ticks on the axis, which looks weird.

*Sample CSS*

So in summary a sample CSS file is similar to below.  The chart plot is based upon [Oracle sample line chart code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI).

```
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 4px;
    /*-fx-border-insets: -2px;*/
}

.axis:top {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.axis:right {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.axis:bottom {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.axis:left {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}

.chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}
```

When plotted, with the above CSS, a sample chart looks like this:

[image: portfolio]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted: just to get rid of those little lines on the axis. This solves it, thank you!